# Swinging Man Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

> Imagine a person of mass $M$ swinging on a playground swing. At the lowest point of motion (where a person moves only horizontally not vertically) the man decides to stand on the swing, assume that his center of mass moves by a distance $l <<L$. The length of the swing chain is $L$ ang angular amplitude of oscillations is theta (which is very small).
>
> Find the work required to do so (by the man).

My attempt:
What I thought was that as the Man's feet stay on the swing during the manoeuvre hence the normal reaction wont have any work hence the only work that needs to be done is to overcome work done by mg and change the mans velocity of center of mass.

(Fun fact: I initally thought that mg won't have any work as it is balanced by normal reaction but I realized that even though a force is balanced doesnt mean it cant contribute towards any work. Here infact the balancing force itself has no work. **Someone please confirm this fact and my thinking.** )

Here is the soln given in my book without reasoning:

https://d3l946twezs300.cloudfront.net/partners/32/6751/solution5.png

edit I followed the given instructions in the green ticked answer to arrive at the correct answer like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U8iNNakUPRrw3mTgl-w89WnR5IRR6mNS/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIK0C43TMX-INY1WZJU0t6H5pAjBbXxl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI: The man is not a rigid body. The man's leg muscles do work on his center of mass. The muscles exert force while the center of mass moves.

Comment: It would help do show your calculations (using Mathjax).

Comment: @SolomonSlow  Yes sir  of course the man is not a rigid body otherwise how could he apply a force?. Sir but you didn't specify that my thinking was correct or not(except for the muscles part) and does the Coriolis force acts on the center of mass of the object ?

Comment: @SolomonSlow if yes then we could straight forward say that the man just needs to overcome Coriolis and mg the straight forward work done would be (mg +Coriolis)*l

Comment: Re, "Can Some kind hearted physicist please confirm my thoughts..." I am not a physicist. Not sure whether I am kind-hearted or not. My dog thinks so, but not everybody else I know agrees. In any case, I don't think that I am qualified to give you a good answer. My prior comment was in response to you saying, "the normal reaction wont have any work." I wasn't entirely sure what that was supposed to mean, but I thought maybe you were saying that the man did no work by standing up.

Comment: NO Worries mate along with your dog I too believe you are kind hearted just like everyone here!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this maneuver quickly (at the lowest point of swing) the man would need to start with his feet on the seat (in a squat). Then he could lift with his arms and legs.  He would need to increase his gravitational energy (mgh) and (in a rotating system) do work against the centrifugal force (m$v^2$/r) (where v is determined by conservation of angular momentum). (That work would require an integral.)

Comment: yes I think so these are the only forces against which he must work and to evaluate the integral we can write v in terms of r(by conserving angular momentum and then integrate it from L to L-l right????

Comment: As Normal reaction doesn't contribute to any work for the man right???? as his feet are stationary right???

Comment: A normal force can do work if it is acting and moving in the direction of motion.

Comment: Thankyou so much kind sir

Comment: Yeah Yeah my bad I meant stationary wrt to bench. actually force was vertical and motion was horizontal. So f.s.cos90=0